# Could not connect to sql server: SQL server Instance failure. (System.Data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I get this error message when I try to connect to Sql Server

```
===================================

Cannot connect to **SQL_ServerName**.

===================================

Instance failure. (System.Data)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, Boolean disableTnir)

   ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was I had two SQL server instance on the same machine.

Both instances were listening to connection on the same port, [as describe in this forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1676381-sql-server-2014-instance-failure-system-data)

### Solution 1: Change one instance to run on another port.

1. Open your Sql Server Configuration Manager
2. Go to `SQL Server Network Configuration` and select `Protocols for YOUR_INSTANCE`.
3. Right-click on `TCP/IP`  `=>` `Properties`
4. Change the port from `1433` to another one. I changed it to `1434`.
5. Restart sql server and it should work.

### Solution 2: Shutdown one sql instance.

1. Go to services
2. Find the instance you want to shutdown.
3. Right-click `=>` Stop

Answer (score 2):

If you have got 2 instances, you take this error. I have MSSQLSERVER and SQL2005 instance name. And after windows server 2008r2 restart, the MSSQLSERVER is working but my default instance SQL2005 is not working. I check the system event log. It says about TCP connection is working another program or service. And I stopped MSSQLSERVER and my default instance SQL2005 started normally... This is port sharing problem.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by stoped all server instance and just run the instance i work with it

1- open sql server configuration manager (if not shown in start menu it's in system32 ) .

2- select SQL Server Services you will get all instances that installed in your pc.

3- stop any instance you dont work with it and start the instance that you work with it.